AWS CloudWatch Log group does not exist
I have created an appsync api. I enabled logging option in setting to see resolver function log event. AppSync auto create link for log group in CloudWatch. But I got an error from that link.
AppSync Setting
Log group in CloudWatch page after I click on the link
CloudWatch Error
I tried to create a log group by using the name that appsync given. After I created the log group, I still could not see the log info.
Create new log group
